# Is it correct to pass the random number generator mt19937 by reference to helper functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

```
int helper( mt19937& generator ){ 

    do stuff; 
    return 0; 

}

#include "helper.h" 
// helper function defined in separate source file and included in header

mt19937 generator(time(NULL));

int main( ) {

    help(generator);

}
```

Is it correct to create and seed the mt19937 random number generator, then pass it by reference to a function for use?

I am doing this because I know I am suppose to only seed mt19937 once. But I have a lot of helper functions in separate source files that need to use a random number generator. E.g. with the shuffle function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is correct to pass the generator around by reference.  The `mt19937` has internal state that needs to be modified to get the next random number.  If you were to pass the generator by value then you would make a copy of that state and then multiple functions would wind up getting the same random number.  This is also why you cannot pass it by `const&` since it would not be able to modify that internal state if it was `const`.

Comment: *"That defeats the purpose of using such a nice generator"* -- Not necessarily. A repeatable sequence is very desirable for some use cases.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley In that case you should seed it with he same seed every run.

Comment: What if you're starting from an advanced state?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh I see.  I'll remove that.  There can be times when you want this.